# Import Excel module installation issues in Sitecore Powershell Extentions

Tags: powershell-extensions, data-migration

We are trying to enable excel data extraction in a machine where MS office is not present. While doing that we are facing issues to enable the `Import-Excel module in SPE`. We are facing the below problems:
[image: ImportExcel module Installtion failure in SPE]

The same issue occurred in `Windows Powershell` as well. But we executed the below commands to get rid of the issue in Windows Powershell.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Then executed the below:

```
Install-Module -Name Import-Excel -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

After that, able to install ImportExcel in Windows PowerShell script. But same commands got failed in Sitecore Powershell.

We are following the below article. But no luck.

https://powershell.one/tricks/parsing/excel

Anybody has come across this issue. Can you please help us to resolve this issue?

Comment: I found this article, please check if it can help you: https://4sysops.com/archives/read-and-write-excel-spreadsheets-with-the-importexcel-powershell-module/

Comment: Thanks Himmat. Commands are working fine in Windows Powershell. But not in SPE. that is the issue we are facing.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, I solved like below.

Before seeing this there is typo in your package name its **ImportExcel** not **Import-Excel**. First check this.

### Run below in Sitecore PowerShell

Below for execution policy and TLS enablement.

```
> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

### Run below in Windows PowerShell

I am switching to windows PowerShell due to no admin privilege's in modifying access in folder.(In my environment)

This is to save the module in your local folder.

```
> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

> `>Register-PSRepository -Default // Run this if you are not register PS repository.It should be like this , in case you register`
> [image]

```
> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
> Save-Module -Name ImportExcel -Path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\temp1'
```

### Run below in Sitecore PowerShell

Now we will install the module in Sitecore PowerShell.

```
> Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

> See its finally installing successfully.
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Foloowed the same steps but end up with errors is Win.Powershell and SPE.

Comment: **Win.PS Error**: WARNING: Unable to resolve package source'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'.PackageManagement\Save-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'ImportExcel'.
**SPE Error**: PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'ImportExcel'. 
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.1\PSModule.psm1:9683 char:34

Comment: Did you enabled TLS in Windows-Powershell, [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 .

Then try save command. I update answer.