# Is there a way to install modules from PSGallery?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have tried installing a script from PSGallery using multiple "tricks" to get around the Windows Security (that prevents accessing the default PS folder), as by default, it results in:

```
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Administrator rights are required to install or update.
Log on to the computer with an account that has Administrator rights, and then try again, 
or install by adding "-Scope CurrentUser" to your command. 
You can also try running the Windows PowerShell session with elevated rights (Run as Administrator).
```

After all attempts, when I got the module saved to a folder Sitecore user has access to (using the `Save-Module` command), and ran `Import-Module -FullyQualifiedName '<path>'` it resulted in `Import-Module : The current provider (Sitecore) cannot open a file.` referring to the `.psd1` file in the module folder.

I used many articles in the process, but [this one](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29348/import-excel-module-installation-issues-in-sitecore-powershell-extentions) seemed the most useful. Also, the answer there, while not providing a solution (because the last part doesn't work), gives hope.

I also couldn't find any mentions of the ability to install modules in the [SPE docs](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/0), nor a denial.

When asking this question here, I'm expecting to receive:

1. A confirmation that the `Install/Import-Module` feature isn't supported.
2. A solution to get around the `The current provider (Sitecore) cannot open a file.` error.
3. Another solution to install the module.

*P.S. No, unfortunately, I don't have the option to grant Windows Admin rights to users*

Looking forward to your replies. Thanks in advance!